# How to create a Quasar Framework boot file for vueI18n@next with the Vue Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

We;re trying to install the new `vueI18n@next` package with Quasar Framework for use with the Vue 2 and the Vue Composition API. The [Vue I18n docs](https://vue-i18n-next.intlify.dev/api/general.html#returns) mention this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createI18n, useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

// call with I18n option
const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'ja',
  messages: { en: { ... } }
})

const App = {
  setup() {
    // ...
    const { t } = useI18n({ ... })
    return { ... , t }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(i18n)
app.mount('#app')
```

When we're trying to translate that to a [Quasar Framework boot file](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files) we get an error on the `app.setup` part:

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import messages from 'src/i18n'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createI18n, useI18n, VueI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    i18n: VueI18n
  }
}

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'en-us',
  fallbackLocale: 'en-us',
  messages,
})

Vue.use(i18n)

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  // Set i18n instance on app
  app.setup = () => {
    const { t } = useI18n()
    return { t }
  }
})
```

Error:

[image]

What is the correct way to install this?

Comment: which error ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quasar is still on Vue 2, not Vue 3. So we're now using the [vue-i18n-composable](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-composable#readme) package instead with this boot file:

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n-composable'
import messages from 'src/i18n'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    i18n: VueI18n
  }
}

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'en-us',
  fallbackLocale: 'en-us',
  messages,
})

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.i18n = i18n
})
```